# Prolog solve Sudoku

Tags: prolog, sudoku, swi-prolog, constraint-programming, clpfd

I'm rather new at Prolog and found this example on swi-prolog.org to solve a sudoku. But I can't run it. I looked up same_length and there is only `same_length/2` not `same_length/1`. Also `all_distinct/2` and not `all_distinct/0`. http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd-sudoku

Here are my errors:

```
ERROR: d:/.../prolog/sudoku.pl:5:10: Syntax error: Operator expected
% d:/.../prolog/sudoku compiled 0.00 sec, 0 clauses
Warning: The predicates below are not defined. If these are defined
Warning: at runtime using assert/1, use :- dynamic Name/Arity.
Warning: 
Warning: all_distinct/1, which is referenced by
Warning:        d:/.../prolog/sudoku.pl:16:8: 2-nd clause of blocks/3
```

And here is the code of SWI-Prolog example:

```
    use_module(library(clpfd)). 

    sudoku(Rows) :-
        length(Rows, 9), maplist(same_length(Rows), Rows),
        append(Rows, Vs),
        Vs in 1..9,
        maplist(all_distinct, Rows),
        transpose(Rows, Columns),
        maplist(all_distinct, Columns),
        Rows = [As,Bs,Cs,Ds,Es,Fs,Gs,Hs,Is],
        blocks(As, Bs, Cs),
        blocks(Ds, Es, Fs),
        blocks(Gs, Hs, Is).

blocks([], [], []). 
blocks([N1,N2,N3|Ns1], [N4,N5,N6|Ns2], [N7,N8,N9|Ns3]) :-
        all_distinct([N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9]),
        blocks(Ns1, Ns2, Ns3).

problem(1, [[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
            [_,_,_,_,_,3,_,8,5],
            [_,_,1,_,2,_,_,_,_],
            [_,_,_,5,_,7,_,_,_],
            [_,_,4,_,_,_,1,_,_],
            [_,9,_,_,_,_,_,_,_],
            [5,_,_,_,_,_,_,7,3],
            [_,_,2,_,1,_,_,_,_],
            [_,_,_,_,4,_,_,_,9]]).
```

I hope you can help me to find my mistake.

Comment: Where's a link to this code? I'm confused by what's meant by `maplist(same_length(Rows, Rows), Rows)`. The rest of it does not seem insane to me at first blush.

Comment: I added it to the description

Comment: I copied and pasted the code off the site myself and it works. In your last edit, you removed the typo I pointed out in my earlier comment; I suggest that you need to try copy-pasting the code again and run the query per the linked page and it will work for you.

Comment: I use swi Prolog and copied it 1 to 1 in sudoku.pl and consulted this file. But i Still get the error

Comment: funny enough. No it works. But i changed not a bit

Comment: I had lots of fun implementing a Sudoku solver/generator in Prolog, some time ago [https://gist.github.com/gerardolima/dc5c81e58eec8fc48f94e4f0138e8f87]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it now already works for you. However, I would still like to take the opportunity to show a few hints that may be useful for you:

### Facts vs. directives

First, why doesn't the code that you post in your answer work?

The Prolog message already gives a pretty good indication:

```
Warning: The predicates below are not defined. ...
...
all_distinct/1, which is referenced by
```

This shows that you are in fact using `all_distinct/1` (*not* `all_distinct/2`!) in your code *somewhere*, and it is not available.

Why? Because `all_distinct/1` is available in `library(clpfd)`, and you are **not importing that library**!

This is a pretty common error among beginners. Take a look at the following line in your program:

```
    use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Contrary to what you may believe, this does **not import** the library! Why? Because, as it stands, this is simply a **Prolog fact** of the form `use_module/1`, similar to the fact:

```
    name(bob).
```

which, likewise, does not name `bob`, but simply states that `name(bob)` *holds*.

What you want instead is to use a **directive** to import a library.

**Directives** are terms of the form `:-(D)`, which can also be written as `:- D` since `(:-)/1` is a prefix **operator**.

Hence, what you *meant* to write is:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

This is a term of the form `:-(T)`, and will be processed as a directive when the file is loaded.

## Convenience definitions

Personally, I often write small Prolog programs, and most of them use CLP(FD) constraints. At some point, I got tired of adding `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).` to all my programs, so I added the following definition to my `~/.emacs`:

```
(global-set-key "\C-cl" (lambda ()
                          (interactive)
                          (insert ":- use_module(library()).")
                          (forward-char -3)))
```

When you now press `C-c l`, the following snippet is inserted at point:

```
:- use_module(library()).
```

and point is placed within the `()` so that you only have to type the actual *name* of the library instead of the whose `:- use_module...etc.` directive.

So, to use `library(clpfd)`, I would simply type:

```
C-c l clpfd
```

After a while, I got tired of that as well, and simply added `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).` to my `~/.swiplrc` configuration file, because almost all programs I write perform integer arithmetic, and so it makes sense for me to make CLP(FD) constraints available in all Prolog programs I write. This is also already the case in systems like GNU Prolog and B-Prolog, for example.

However, I still have kept the `.emacs` definition, because sometimes I need to import other libraries, and I find typing the whole `:- use_module...` directive too cumbersome and error-prone.